# How do i add a space between the word and the (:)?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code:

```
public static void ExtractDateTime(string text, List<string> newText, List<string> dateTime)
{
   string pattern1 = "<span style=color:#000099;>(?'hebrew'[^<]*)</span>";
   Regex expr1 = new Regex(pattern1, RegexOptions.Singleline);
   MatchCollection matches = expr1.Matches(text);
   foreach (Match match in matches)
   {
     string hebrew = match.Groups["hebrew"].Value;
     string pattern2 = @"[^\s$]*:[^:]*:\s+\d\d:\d\d";
     Regex expr2 = new Regex(pattern2);
     Match match2 = expr2.Match(hebrew);
     string results = match2.Value;
     dateTime.Add("דווח במקור " + results);
   }
}
```

In the end for example on dateTime that is List i have in index 0 this line:

```
דווח במקור בתאריך: 18.03.14  שעה: 11:36
```

I want to add a space between the word שווה and :
So it will be like   : שווה
And not :שווה

How can i do it ?

Comment: do you want space between just `:` and `שווה` ? or you want to add space after each `:` ?

Comment: What is the Regional Language do you use in your Windows? Is the text direction from right to left or left to right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may help you.

```
string s = "דווח במקור בתאריך: 18.03.14  שעה: 11:36";
int i = s.IndexOf("שעה");
s = s.Insert(i + "שעה".Length, " ");
```

[image]

Comment: I tried my code and it doesn't work but that's not happening here. What happens is that the string remains the same. I'm guessing the mix of hebrew and digits on a string is the issue here

Comment: Do you know what is the language is used in this text @chiapa?

Comment: That's Hebrew, I guess

Comment: Yes, That's Hebrew and since it is a Right-to-left language , the correct direction of writing is Right-to-left. That's why when you try to store that string in variable the text will be transformed in Right-to-Left.]

Comment: Well done @Nimesh! I had never stumbled upon right-to-left languages before

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
results = results.Replace(":שעה :", "שעה");
```

Comment: have you checked above example?

Comment: you mean the answer I'm suggesting?

Comment: Yes, I think the text displayed in the question is right to left. so when you place this string into any variable it shows left to right.

Comment: look at the image i have added in my answer. @chiapa